# How to prove the uniqueness of a number pattern (114 and 506)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have found two integers with the following behavior and need a proof of their uniqueness:

```
114 / 2         = 57
median(1..57)   = 29
57 * 29         = 1653
where
the 16th prime  = 53
```

```
506 / 2         = 253
median(1..253)  = 127
253 * 127       = 32131
where
the 32nd prime  = 131
```

Here is a YAFU Windows interface: https://github.com/heliwave/PrimeCalculator

[image: 114 Properties] [image: 506 Properties]
[image: Color codes]

I have written a C# search program (https://heliwave.github.io/IP.zip) to find similar integers n with n/2 = h, median(1..h) = m, h*m = IP where I is the prime index of the prime P.

As numbers went up, I and the P seemed to diverge away from expected Primes and their Indices. No matches were found up to I = 7000000.

**Can someone please outline a proof of how to prove this divergence mathematically?**

Other relationships between 114 and 506:

```
114th prime     = 619
506th composite = 621
where
114 + 506       = 620
```

```
114th composite                              = 150
114th composite with composite digit sum     = 220
114th composite with non-composite digit sum = 436
where
436 + 220 - 150                              = 506
```

```
506th composite                              = 621
506th composite with composite digit sum     = 886
506th composite with non-composite digit sum = 1943
where
1943 - 886 - 621                             = 114th non-additive composite
```

Moreover,

```
There are 16 prime numbers with prime digit sums up to 114:
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 23,  29, 41, 43, 47, 61, 67, 83, 89, 101, 113.

There are 53 composite numbers with composite digit sums up to 114: 
4, 6, 8, 9, 15, 18, 22, 24, 26, 27, 28, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 51, 54, 55, 57, 60, 62, 63, 64, 66, 68, 69, 72, 75, 77, 78, 80, 81, 82, 84, 86, 87, 88, 90, 91, 93, 95, 96, 99, 105, 108, 112, 114.
```

```
There are 42 prime numbers with non-prime digit sums up to 506:
13, 17, 19, 31, 37, 53, 59, 71, 73, 79, 97, 103, 107, 109, 127, 149, 163, 167, 181, 211, 233, 239, 251, 257, 271, 277, 293, 307, 347, 349, 367, 383, 389, 419, 431, 433, 439, 457, 479, 491, 499, 503.

  32 non-additive primes with a digit sum != 10
  10 non-additive primes with a digit sum  = 10:   19, 37, 73, 109, 127, 163, 181, 271, 307, 433.
  19 + 37 + 73 + 109 + 127 + 163 + 181 + 271 + 307 + 433 = Sum of the first 31 prime numbers from 2 to 127 = 1720

There are 131 composite numbers with non-composite digit sums up to 506:
10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 21, 25, 30, 32, 34, 38, 49, 50, 52, 56, 58, 65, 70, 74, 76, 85, 92, 94, 98, 100, 102, 104, 106, 110, 111, 115, 119, 120, 122, 124, 128, 133, 140, 142, 146, 148, 155, 160, 164, 166, 175, 182, 184, 188, 200, 201, 203, 205, 209, 210, 212, 214, 218, 221, 230, 232, 236, 238, 245, 247, 250, 254, 256, 265, 272, 274, 278, 287, 289, 290, 292, 296, 298, 300, 302, 304, 308, 319, 320, 322, 326, 328, 335, 340, 344, 346, 355, 362, 364, 368, 371, 377, 380, 382, 386, 388, 391, 395, 403, 407, 410, 412, 416, 418, 425, 427, 430, 434, 436, 445, 452, 454, 458, 469, 470, 472, 476, 478, 481, 485, 490, 494, 496, 500, 502, 506.
```

Full details at: https://heliwave.github.io/506.pdf

How to prove the uniqueness of these lovely ♥ Twin Numbers ♥ 114 and 506?

If it helps, you can assume:

```
n is a sphenic integer (3D)
h is a semi-prime (2D)
m is a prime (1D)
1 is the unit (0D)
```

Comment: is the median always prime ? if so then 5 mod 6 appended prime needs 1 or 2 mod 3 index, if 1 mod 6 then appended prime needs 0, or 2 mod 3 index.

Comment: Yes, n is a (3D) integer with three distinct prime factors. h is a (2D) integer with two distinct prime factors, and m is a (1D) integer with 1 prime factor (i.e is prime). I like to think of integers geometrically so they form 1D, 2D, 3D, ..., nD shapes.

Comment: aka you like n almost primes.

Comment: n should be a sphenic number = a composite with three distinct prime factors.

Comment: end numbers is of form $2r^2-r$ where $r$ is prime, as $r^2$ is 1 mod 24 things can be sieved mod 24.

Comment: I have updated the question  with screenshots. Please explain to me what do you mean by end numbers (IP or m?) and why $2 r^2 - r$?

Comment: mean of $1$ and $2r-1$ is $r$; $r\cdot (2r-1)=2r^2-r$

Comment: $322$ also has this property. The product you get is $13041$ and $41$ is the 13th prime. Or don't you allow the leading zero?

Comment: Never considered leading zero(s). Thank you for this example.
I actually didn't find these numbers, they found me :) The Quran has 114 chapters and the 57th chapter consists of 29 verses. That forced me to find 506.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of complications in an easy problem statement, but anyways. If your original 'magic number' is $2n$, then you have $\frac{2n}{2}=n$ and the median of the first $n$ naturals is $\frac{n+1}{2}$. We thus need the value:
$$T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
to be the concatentation of a prime number's index and value. Clearly, $\{T_n\ \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is the set of triangular numbers.

We can see that a necessary and sufficient condition for $x$ to be of the form $T_n$ is $8x^2+1$ being a perfect square. We can thus run a program to check for the values where $8x^2+1$ is prime for:
$$x=10^{\lfloor \log p_i \rfloor +1} \cdot i+p_i$$
which is basically the concatenation of the index and prime value.

I run a program to check for all values with $p_i<10^6$. It turns out that there is only one other value that works, which is $x=79401$, giving the third 'magic number' $2n=796$. Thus, the values $114$ and $506$ are not the only such numbers.

However, there is a high possibility that these three might be the only numbers satisfying the property since triangular numbers are quite scarce. The program generating only three possible values supports the heuristics.

```
796 / 2          = 398
median(1..398)   = 199.5
398 * 199.5      = 79401
where
the 79th prime   = 401
```

Comment: Dear Haran, I accept your answer for stating "Triangular numbers are rare." although I limit myself to integer domain. Here is another example using half instead of median and index|composite instead of index|prime.

Comment: 13444 / 2 = 6722  __  median(1..6722) = 3361  __  6722 * 3361 = 22592642  __  the 2259th composite = 2642

Comment: Since you have such clear understanding of these "magic numbers", what do you think of the other properties stated in the question linking 114 and 506?

Comment: https://oeis.org/draft/A331998
Giovanni Resta found a fouth number. T(18619378) = 173340627863131 where P1733406 = 27863131 so it seems there are infinite but very sparse such numbers in the series.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very rough approximation. The probability that any given number $IP$ being in the form of $h*m$ is approximately $\frac 1{\sqrt {IP}}$. But the probability of a number being in your form of $I$ append with $P$ is $\frac I{IP}=\frac 1P$. Using the approximation $P\approx I\ln{I}$, and doing the integral, it converges. So there's probably only a finite amount of numbers that match your description. But I don't believe there will be a proof to your claim though.

Comment: Thank you @David Cheng for the answer. I was hoping it would diverge, not converge. And if it alternates then could match a big number.